# How to file a bug report for a specific Ubuntu release?

Tags: package-management, security

I imagine if I want a package updated in an LTS, such as 12.04, it has be for a very good reason. The actual package I am interested in is picolisp:

It has a (probably also affecting security!) bug which is fixed in picolisp upstream.  How should the bug be filed to get attention for not only 12.10 but also 12.04?

Should the fix be a minimal patch to only fix the crash and security issue, or should the fix be an outright upgrade to picolisp latest upstream?

I have read the bug report FAQ but could only find very general advice on how to file bug reports, more aimed at and users than people with knowledge about the actual packages.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/picolisp/+bug/956731

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: I don't think so. I can not find any answer there, and I did read that page first. @Mitch

Comment: Sorry, that did not help :(

Comment: Have you tried the standard command 'ubuntu-bug picolisp'? You can explain your point of view in the bug report. And there **are** package updates even on an LTS release especially if it's a security problem.

Comment: Apparently I need a sponsor for the bug... @devius, yes I tried that command. I don't need to submit a stack trace or anything, we know what the problem is and it's patched in later versions of picolisp.

Comment: So you are the package maintainer for picolisp? I thought you were just a regular user that stumbled upon a bug.

Comment: No, not maintainer, but I know the upstream author of PicoLisp and I am rather familiar with the PicoLisp code base. @devius

Comment: @Devius, actually I don't quite understand who *is* package maintainer or if anyone is, for picolisp.

Comment: Well, that document you linked to in your answer below seems to be geared towards package maintainers and not end-users. If you fill in the bug description with the informations in "procedures" it will probably help in speeding up the process. Other than that I can't help you any further as I'm not familiar with the process of packaging in Ubuntu.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3603/discussion-between-amigable-clark-kant-and-devius)

Answer (score 2):

I think [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) solves my problem, specifically steps 1-6 under "Procedures".